# Toggle jQuery Mobile Panel through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Implemented a jQuery Mobile Panel in a screen like below which loads a iFrame

```
<div data-role="panel" id="popupPanel1" data-theme="a" data-position="right" data-dismissible="false" data-display="push">
    <iframe src="" name="cFrame" id="cFrame">
     Browser does not support iFrame. Please contact your administrator.
    </iframe>
</div>
<iframe src="" name="mFrame" id="mFrame">
     Browser does not support iFrame. Please contact your administrator.
</iframe>
```

Button to open Panel is loaded under "mFrame" iFrame so while clicking that after some doing some functionality triggered to load the external content, I have added the code to open panel through JS `$("#popupPanel1").panel("open");` I tried to change it to `$("#popupPanel1").panel("toggle");`

But which makes the popup to close it; after debugging the reason for that is the Panel gets opened before it and so it gets closed. Also I tried by checking if it has the "ui-panel-open" class which results in same it displays and then it gets closed.

Comment: Can you edit this fiddle to reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/n5hd1qy5/ ?  toggle seems to work fine...

Comment: @ezanker Thanks, I tried to reproduce the issue but I couldn't. Sorry I missed to provide few more detail. Edited the question..

Comment: I tried various ways.. the reason behind the "toggle" not working is the Panel gets opened before the `$("#popupPanel1").panel("open");` / `$("#popupPanel1").panel("toggle");` line, so while it comes to toggle it gets closed.